# How to HLS in Wowza with pre-recorded videos?

Tags: wowza, http-live-streaming, transcode

I have a wowza streaming engine in my server which is serving live and vod. I want some of my prerecorded videos to serve in HLS vod which are in MOV format. I am successfully able to place this file to `install-dir/content/` and get the stream.

But, My problem is, player loads video in high resolution and takes too much time to load, but the resolution stays the same, while resolution should have dropped down. I have seen that wowza streaming engine places different resolution like `filename_360p.mp4 filename_480p.mp4`. But In this case it only have one file with high resolution. How can solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Currently Wowza does not do transcoding (or transrate) of ondemand videos. In other words, you need to create the different version of the files by yourself.

Please note that although this is not supported directly, there are some known work arounds to manage this automatically. Basically the work around is to use the live transcoding module of Wowza and recording the transcoded streams. If you do not have a live stream, you will need to stream the files live first.